# Razor elements not recognized

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

When starting up my Blazor Server solution everything seems fine. It builds and all custom elements in the razor files look fine with highlighted green color (using black theme).

But when making a tiny change somewhere in the project, no matter what it is, all custom razor elements to turn blue with error indicators, and it shows the message "found markup element with unexpected name".

I think this kind of behavior may be caused by a conflict somewhere. But I don't know how to find it. I can't find any errors in the Output-window.

Is there a way to track down this problem?

Edit: The way I am dealing with it now, which is cumbersome and not good, is that I clean the solution, close it, delete the .vs folder and open the solution again. Then everything is fine... until I make changes.

Answer (score 2):

I believe sometime I have this issue too.

When you include your razor elements in your pages, they are basically `html` tags and the IDE sometimes it will give an error and sometimes it will not because it could be some legit html tag. But the razor elements won't be loaded.

Make sure to include all the namespaces of the razor elements in the pages that you are using them, even better, include the namespaces in `_Imports.razor` file only once.

Demonstration:

[image: Animation for razor components with and without adding namespaces]

---

**Note:** For older versions of Visual Studio IDE, if the issue persists even by adding namespaces, you can try to remove any mention of the razor element file in the project XML file (csproj file) such as `<Content Remove="Components\MyRazorComponent.razor" />`. Then the razor element will be found.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily work.  Some times VS is gonna be VS, no matter what you do.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Do you mean adding razor elements namespaces in the pages or _import.razor file still VS doesn't detect the elements sometimes and shows error? Could you clarify? And what version of VS you are using?

Comment: I have added all namespaces one way or the other, or else it wouldn't build like my project does.

Comment: @MaxP Even if you didn't add namespaces it will still build and run, but the elements will show as blue and won't be loaded. But you say that you already added the namespaces. Could you check if the elements are compiled to remove in project xml file. I have updated my answer on that note. Does it still not fix the issue?

Comment: @Ibrahim Timinimi, that is true. But my solution first build and every thing is normal and works. But the problem starts once something is changed. It can be anything. I add a new file or something.

Comment: @MaxP You can try use different IDE like Jetbrains or editor like Vscode just to see if can capture the anomaly. Also during building, check the output line by line even though there is no error and build successfuly, maybe you will sniff the issue out. Additionally, close VS and delete the bin and obj folder completely and open VS again. Maybe comment all razor component and enable one by one to see what caused the issue

Comment: @Ibrahim TImimi  Yes, once in a while, VS just gets overwhelmed and the Intellisense just stops working.  It has always been like this.  If you're sure your markup is fine, you can just ignore it and run the project anyway..  Otherwise, you can try closing and reloading a component, or closing and reopening VS.  There are several other ways to get Intellisense to start working again-- deleting certain project folders, turning Intellisense off and then on again, etc.

Comment: I added info about how I deal with the problem now, which is closing and deleting .vs folder. But I have to do this every 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score -1):

I also have had this problem a lot of times with VSCode.  Another thing to try, which helped me just now is to add a @namespace to the component that cant be found. This has helped me just now when I tried it, now my component is found again :)